# Game engine won't render textures in GLSL and when playing in Multitexture

Tags: texturing, 3d-view

I've been having this issue when attempting to test the textures in my game. Whenever you press P to load the game in Multitexture, it acts as if there are no materials or textures at all. They do render in the view port in Multitexture. I was originally using GLSL rendering but the textures never rendered at all! I've unwrapped the textured meshes to no avail.

Here is the .blend file if anyone needs it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4PjIShKrRfjMXJBcU9KelJISlk/view?usp=sharing

[image: This is a gif of the GLSL render not working]

Comment: You can't use the Blender Game Engine in *Multitexture* mode, only GLSL is supported as far as I know. Also your file has wrong permissions for download, use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com instead.

Comment: Are your textures properly loaded into the texture slots of the materials, or are you testing just images loaded into the uv image editor and unwrapped to?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Multitexture mode has worked for me in the past, back when I first worked with the Blender Game Engine. I also have updated the post with a working link.

Comment: @CraigDJones I had assumed that I did, but I went to double check and it turns out either Blender did not save it or I must not have done that in the first place. Thank you.